# Finding the longest substring of string (case non-sensitive)

Tags: python

I need to write a case non-sensitive code that finds the longest substring of any string and returns the corresponding part of the original string without affecting the original case.

A unique substring cannot contain any repeated letters.

It should work like this: ghHcd => Hcd

My attempt is below but it is stuck in an infinite loop due to reasons which are beyond my understanding.

Edit: My goal is to achieve this without using regular expressions.

```
def longest_unique_substring(text):
    longest_substring = ""
    temp_string = ""
    i = 0
    while len(text) > i:
        if text.lower()[i] not in temp_string.lower():
            temp_string += text[i]
        elif text.lower()[i] in temp_string.lower():
            if temp_string > longest_substring:
                longegst_substring = temp_string
            temp_string = ""
            i -= 1
            continue
        i += 1
    return longest_substring
```

Comment: do you want the longest substring with no repeated letters?

Comment: So a substring begins with a capital letter and ends with the last letter before another cpital letter?

Comment: FYI you get an infinite loop because i+1 and i-1 get repeatedly hit, so i is always `< len(text)`

Comment: @Ukulele Yes, that's my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modification works for me:

```
def longest_unique_substring(test):
    longest_substring = ""
    temp_string = ""
    for char in test:
        if char.lower() in temp_string.lower():
            temp_string = temp_string[temp_string.lower().rfind(char.lower())+1:]
        temp_string += char
        if len(longest_substring) < len(temp_string):
            longest_substring = temp_string
    return longest_substring
```

Now `longest_unique_substring('ghHcd')` outputs `'Hcd'`